# keyboard backlight Acer Nitro5 AN515-55 Ubuntu 20.10 works but 2 question

Tags: keyboard, brightness, acer, backlight, 20.10

My Acer nitro5 AN5-15-55 laptop keyboard  backlight is working , only red is available, (and I cannot adjust keyboard backlight brightness), but

1. the back light 'sleeps' when I am not typing? I can't see anything before typing. How to keep the backlght always on? (The reason is when its dark I cant see the keyboard letters at all in beginning , it only lights up when I type so I have to press the space bar or make typo always first time to enable the back light on in Ubuntu 20.10?)
2. Also in Windows I am able to adjust the keyboard backlight different colours, but how to adjust the keyboard backilght colours in Ubuntu 20.10? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

For  my question 1) "the back light 'sleeps' when I am not typing? I can't see anything before typing. How to keep the backlght always on? (The reason is when its dark I cant see the keyboard letters at all in beginning , it only lights up when I type so I have to press the space bar or make typo always first time to enable the back light on in Ubuntu 20.10?)"

- (SOLVED): reboot, press F2 to enter BIOS. In BIOS Main section there should be a setting "Keyboard Backlight Sleep" , it is enabled by default so then set to "disable". Save and exit bios.

In ubuntu 20.10 now my keyboard is peristent ON. Success.

for part 2) change  keyboard backlight colours if you are sure RGB keyboard then try "OpenRGB" - https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB and (must first) check if your RGB keyboard is listed before proceeding. (Some MSI users have bricked motherboards without checking first so read the details pre-installation). Alternatives are here also here as well - https://github.com/withinboredom/system-76-keyboards  here - https://github.com/Gibtnix/MSIKLM and here - https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore

(Credit also to batmalin at Acer community)

Comment: Re part 2). What option did you choose? it seems OpenRGB does not work.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop has no drivers for linux and I'm stuck with blue, can't turn it off, change color or brightness.. You probably will be stuck too if there is no driver available for linux. 
**Try contacting Acer and have them confirm it.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 4-zone keyboard, this should work:
https://github.com/JafarAkhondali/acer-predator-turbo-and-rgb-keyboard-linux-module